# Can't tell if apache is running on Mavericks

Tags: macos, apache

Why can't I see httpd in activity monitor nor top in Mavericks?

Comment: Did you check http://localhost:80/server-status

Answer (score 4):

1. Activity Monitor default view of the process list is 'My Processes':

[image: standard]

2. Switch to 'All Processes' in the menubar to additionally see other users' - like root or _www - processes:

   [image: view]
3. Check again in 'Activity Monitor'

[image: all]

4. If it's still not visible it's not running.
5. httpd not running is default for Mavericks client and server.

Answer (score 3):

You could also open a terminal window and type the following:
ps aux | grep "httpd"